# sphero_ros with indigo

Tags: ros, ubuntu, packages, ubuntu-trusty, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I a learning ROS and I have installed indigo and I am running ubuntu 14.04. I have a sphero that I would like to experiment with and I have tried installing the sphero package via "apt-get install sphero_ros" but apt-get cant seem to find the package. I have checked that ubuntu allows "restricted," "universe," and "multiverse".

1. Is there something else I need to do to tell ubuntu where to find this package?
2. The only documentation i can find for this package is for groovy. Are packages for older ROS distros viable for new distros?

Thanks in advance for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188221/sphero_ros-with-indigo/) by [gideon](https://answers.ros.org/users/19874/gideon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. It looks like the docs are wrong about the package name in the tutorials. Since the docs are part of the repository, you should file a bug against the [sphero_ros bugtracker](https://github.com/mmwise/sphero_ros/issues)
2. It looks like they haven't released a version of spehro_ros for any of the newer ROS releases, so you won't be able to use the packaged version. You should still be able to install sphero_ros from source: https://github.com/mmwise/sphero_ros

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1